# Running python programmes for the command line

Tags: python, bash, command-line

I am trying to run a python programme called helloWorld.py from the command line on MacOS.

I am typing into bash:

```
Ryans-MacBook-Air:~ ryanunderwood$ python3 helloWorld.py
```

But I am getting the following:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'helloWorld.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

There is definitely a file with this name in the directory. Why is this programme not running?

Comment: use `python3 ./helloworld.py` instead.

Comment: Type `ls helloWorld.py` into your terminal and report the results.

Comment: @A.L.: but that's not required on my Mac. I have bog-standard Python and Python3 installations, and they both work as far as Current Working Directories are concerned just like *all other software*.

Answer (score -1):

Try `./helloworld.py` or `python3. /hello World.py`

And make sure you have the right permissions

Comment: What do you mean by permissions? I am a beginner and don't know what permissions are.